# Why surjective functions is retractive? Also why injective one = the axiom of choice?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, category-theory, relations

'In the category of sets, every monomorphism (injective function) with a non-empty domain is a section, and every epimorphism (surjective function) is a retraction; the latter statement is equivalent to the axiom of choice.'
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)
Hence, Why surjective functions is retractive? Also why injective one = the axiom of choice?

Useful reading summary from Sections and Retractions http://theurbanengine.com/blog//sections-and-retractions

Comment: It is a bit unclear; What are you asking?

Comment: If a function $f:X\to Y$ is surjective, then for every element $y\in Y$ you can chose an element $x_y\in f^{-1}(\{y\})$ ths gives you the inverse function (a section). Hence $f$ is a retraction.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov Great! Thank you!

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov I have updated the Q, hope it's clearer.

Comment: Injective one $\neq$ axiom of choice; the possibility of finding a section for a retraction is equivalent to the axiom of choice, since you chose in the prefaces of the points from the codomain. You chose simultaneously in the family of sets one element per member of the family. Then you just prove that sections are monos.

Comment: I would recommend to read ``Sets for Mathematics'' by Lawvere and Rosebrugh http://library.lol/main/E9D18B64F808A3CE0880B9490D6AD538

Comment: Thank you very much!